# how to dynamically add a row in database through web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have two windows application in C# one user side and other admin side..When I run the windows application at the user side, it should make a web service call and through web service it should add a row into the database present at the admin side..Also the row that is to be added in the database should be containing the details entered by the user..can any1 please tel me whether this is possible or not and if yes then how??

Comment: This is jsut lazy. Off course this can be done, ask a spesfic question and not "Do the work for me"

Comment: It is possible, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Make a WebService method that takes values of the parameters you need to add to the database. You call this method from users application and pass all the needed information like to a normal method. Then implement the methods body to use this information to add a row in the db table. What exactly do you mean by how? Which part?

EDIT: If you are new to web services then this task may not be straight forward for you. I am a Java programmer so I won't help you with the coding in C#. You might want to read more on WCF which is an important API for a C# developer and might help you both with WebService and Database access. You can find lots of tutorials on the internet to implement both. You can also choose a different approach than WCF but i think its the best choice if you want to stick with C# for longer. This might be very helpful for you:
[WCF, Web services or ADO.NET data services: What shall I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245121/wcf-web-services-or-ado-net-data-services-what-shall-i-use)

Comment: thank you sooo much..actually m new to C# programming so i do not have much idea as to how to proceed with the coding..so by how i meant : how to proceed with the coding..